# Web page that visualizes Android Built-in Drawables

Tags: android

Android comes with many built-in drawables that are listed on [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable) page. Is there any page where one can see what each of these drawables **looks like**?

E.g., we need to display a green check and red cross depending upon whether a web request succeeded or not. We would like to see if there is any built-in drawable we could use for this instead of creating our own drawables. But the web page linked does not show how the drawables look like so we don't know if there is a built-in drawable that works for us.

Is no such web page exists, does anyone know how one can iterate over the built-in collection of drawables? Then, we could try writing a program ourselves to do the visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MgVLckLRUq4LshuM0B8vYexP5BTwWEGd/view?usp=sharing) is an app to visualize the built in icons in a photo gallery. It lets you quickly browse the built in icons and search what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but if you are using Android Studio, try right clicking the resource folder -> New -> Image Asset and then choosing one of the icons. It gives you a preview of what the icons look like.